# What is the best practice to execute a SQL statement right after MySQL initialization?

Tags: mysql, sql, initialization

I want to execute a **SQL statement** just after the **MySQL** daemon starts or finalizes its initialization process.

Basically I am  looking for something like `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` or the `@boot` option of crontab, but *specific* to MySQL.

I can add a script to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, or add a `@boot` cron as last resort as I mentioned before. But it is really important for me to be able to assure that this set of statements are executed *before* any script or application starts hitting MySQL.

I have also considered hacking the `/etc/init.d/mysqld` script, but these solutions are kind of ugly. I have checked the documentation relative to starting MySQL and extensively searched for an answer without luck.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you run the script from your application initialization instead of your mySQL initialization?

Comment: The application is scattered across different scripts and such, there is no single point of entry. And I want to be sure this custom initialization is executed before any of the components hit the DB.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [init-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) option.